# Is it possible to update a part of page every second with Razor.Html.Partial?

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I am using `Nancy` with razor engine and i want to execute a function that updates part of the page every second. What i have done already is i created a simple partial view named `_partial.cshtml`

Code:

```
<p>@System.DateTime.Now</p>
```

and in my main view i set an interval to log the value of that partial view every second

Code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(@Html.Partial("../_partial.cshtml", null));
}, 1000);
```

However this renders the same value every time because it is interpreted at the client (chrome in this case) as a static valye and not dynamic anymore... so how could i get around that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an action which returns a partial view from the server. In the Javascript code, you have to write an AJAX GET / POST request which should be placed within the setInterval() block. If it is plain Asp.net MVC, I would do as follows. For Nancy, it should not be much different.

```
// Controller Action Method, assuming name of controller as DataController
public ActionResult RealTimeData()
{
  return PartialView("_partial");
}

// Javascript Code
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('@Url.Action("RealTimeData", "Data")', null, function(data, status, xhr){
     // Update the UI.
  }).fail(function(x, status, err){
     // Handle errors
  });
},1000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't pass model to nancy

Comment: Can you share the updated javascript code and server side Nancy code?